# Recreating Electoral Targeting Package

Tags: r, plyr, pscl

I'm really into politics and elections and I'm just getting into learning R and I would like to recreate the process laid out in this [blog](https://www.r-bloggers.com/aggreate-electoral-targeting-with-r/) with new data from a local county. I've been able to get through most of the process in the blog reliably with my modified code until I get to district analyze.

```
datas <- district.analyze(data)
```

The author analyzes specific house districts whereas I would prefer to analyze the county as a whole. I modified the code to use U.S. House as my target district because it encompasses the entire county.

I want to know if anyone has suggestions on why I am unable to get the precinct level summaries from this county data. I get an error like this one:

```
> Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
no rows to aggregate
In addition: Warning message:
In min(adf[, "rep_turnout_pct"], na.rm = TRUE) :
```

I only get this error when I have "NA" in the data. When I have "0" in place of the blanks the district.analyze works, however the "0" throws off all of the equations.

the minimum amount of code I can get to reproduce this is:

```
library(plyr)

 major.party.bias <- function(adf) {    

 # aggregate base partisan vote -  lowest non-zero turnout by party, given any election

 abpv_rep <- min(adf[adf$rep_turnout_pct,"rep_turnout_pct"],na.rm=TRUE)
abpv_dem <- min(adf[adf$dem_turnout_pct,"dem_turnout_pct"],na.rm=TRUE)

 # aggregate base partisan is combination of major parties worst scores
 base_abpv = abpv_rep + abpv_dem
 # swing is what is left after the aggregate base partisan support is removed
 abpv_swing = 1.0 - base_abpv

 # remove elections w/ no contender ie NA rep or NA dem turnout
 tsa <- adf[which(!is.na(adf$dem_turnout) & !is.na(adf$rep_turnout)),]  
 # add a abs difference of rep v dem column
 tsa[,"spread"] <- abs(tsa$dem_turnout_pct - tsa$rep_turnout_pct)

 # average party performance - average of the top 3 best matched races (sorted by abs(rep-dem) performance)
 app_dem <- mean(tsa[order(tsa$spread)[1:3],]$dem_turnout_pct)
 app_rep <- mean(tsa[order(tsa$spread)[1:3],]$rep_turnout_pct)

 # aggreage soft partisan vote - difference between the average worst over each year and the absolute worst (aggregate base partisan vote)
 tsa <- adf[which(!is.na(adf$rep_turnout)),]
 abpv_rep_soft <- mean(aggregate(tsa$rep_turnout_pct,tsa["year"],min)[,"x"]) - abpv_rep
 tsa <- adf[which(!is.na(adf$dem_turnout)),]
 abpv_dem_soft <- mean(aggregate(tsa$dem_turnout_pct,tsa["year"],min)[,"x"]) - abpv_dem

 # tossup is everything left after we take out base and soft support for both major parties
 abpv_tossup = abs(1.0 - abpv_rep_soft - abpv_rep - abpv_dem_soft - abpv_dem)

 partisan.rep <- abpv_rep + abpv_rep_soft
 partisan.dem <- abpv_dem + abpv_dem_soft

 return (data.frame(partisan.base=base_abpv,partisan.swing=abpv_swing,tossup=abpv_tossup,
                    app.rep=app_rep,base.rep=abpv_rep,soft.rep=abpv_rep_soft,app.dem=app_dem,base.dem=abpv_dem,soft.dem=abpv_dem_soft,
                    partisan.rep=partisan.rep, partisan.dem=partisan.dem)) 
}


 project.turnout <- function(adf,years=c(2012,2014,2016),target.district.type="U.S. House",similar.district.types=c('U.S. Senate','State Senate', 'State Auditor', 'Governor'),top.ballot.district.type="U.S. Senate") {
 # look for good elections in years
 case.type = 0
 gl <- adf[which(adf$year %in% years & adf$district_type == target.district.type & !is.na(adf$dem_turnout) & !is.na(adf$rep_turnout)),] 
 # case 1 - major parties ran in 2001,2005 (governor + lt governor + HD)
 # we'll calculate the average_turnout x downballot_turnout
 proj.turnout <- 0.0
 if(nrow(gl) >= 2 ){
     down.ballot.turnout <- mean((gl$dem_turnout + gl$rep_turnout) / gl$total_registration)     
     gl <- adf[which(adf$year %in% years & adf$district_type == top.ballot.district.type),]             
     top.ticket.turnout <- mean(gl$total_turnout / gl$total_registration)
     gl <- adf[which(adf$year %in% years & !is.na(adf$dem_turnout) & !is.na(adf$rep_turnout)),]             
     avg.turnout <- mean((gl$dem_turnout + gl$rep_turnout) / gl$total_registration) 
     runoff <- down.ballot.turnout / top.ticket.turnout
     proj.turnout <- runoff * avg.turnout
     case.type = 1
 }  
 # case 2 - missing major party candidate in ''years'', so we 'll just take the average of what we've got walking backwards from the last known good year
 # need more than one HD election
 else {     
     gl <- adf[which(adf$district_type == target.district.type & !is.na(adf$dem_turnout) & !is.na(adf$rep_turnout)),]   
     if(nrow(gl) >= 1 ) {
         # calculate the average turnout of at least one election
        proj.turnout <- mean((gl$dem_turnout + gl$rep_turnout) / gl$total_registration)                     
         case.type = 2
     }
     else {
         # we dont have any evenly matched house races so we'll look at ''similar.district.types'' as a substitute
         gl <- adf[which((adf$district_type %in% similar.district.types) & !is.na(adf$dem_turnout) & !is.na(adf$rep_turnout)),] 
         if(nrow(gl) >= 1) {
             proj.turnout <- mean((gl$dem_turnout + gl$rep_turnout) / gl$total_registration)                                        
             case.type = 3
         }
         else {
             proj.turnout <- 0          
             case.type = 4
         }
     }
 }
 # project the actual registration based on the known last registration in the df
 reg <- adf[1,]$last_registration
 proj.turnout.count <- proj.turnout  * reg return(data.frame(proj.turnout.percent=proj.turnout,proj.turnout.count=proj.turnout.count,current.reg=reg,case.type=case.type))
}

  # apply the major party bias to the projected turnout 
apply.turnout <- function(adf) {
   # take proj.turnout.count (from project.turnout) and combine it 
 with partisan percentages from major.party.bias


  adf$proj.turnout.dem <- floor(adf$proj.turnout.count * adf$app.dem)
  adf$proj.turnout.rep <- floor(adf$proj.turnout.count * adf$app.rep)
  adf$votes.to.win <- floor(adf$proj.turnout.count/2)+1

 return(adf)
 }


 district.analyze <- function(dis) {
ret <- ddply(dis, .(precinct_name), function(x) merge(project.turnout(x),major.party.bias(x)))
ret <- apply.turnout(ret)
return(ret)
 }
```

My data is a large dataset I read into R from .csv:

```
## Data given as Google Sheets
library(gsheet)
url <-"https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E4P0rfDVWEepbGHwX58qNSWN5vWd3iQU/view?usp=sharing"
df <- gsheet2tbl(url)
```

Comment: This is an interesting question! Can you please edit it into a [mcve] so that people can better help?

Comment: @Stedy I have edited the post, it's still a lot, but I hope it's closer to what you requested. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Because URLs tend to rot, it's better if, as @Steady pointed out, make a minimal reproducible example. I'll just work with what you've given us though.

I first import your code from GitHub:

```
## Matt's code from GitHub
library(RCurl)
script <-
  getURL(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwtxw2/R-Aggpol-Boone-Test/master/R%20Data",
    ssl.verifypeer = FALSE
  )
eval(parse(text = script))
```

Then I read in the data you gave in the Google Sheets

```
## Data given as Google Sheets
library(gsheet)
url <-
  "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HJjLDFEiLixQZLeMtliXyojsPtWh6XM9AZjJbc-96tA/edit?usp=sharing"
df <- gsheet2tbl(url)
```

Now, the problem was, I believe, that there are no district numbers if U.S. Senate subset is called---they are NA values.

```
## There are no district numbers if subsetted to U.S. Senate.
table((df %>% dplyr::filter(district_type == "U.S. Senate"))$district_number)
sum(!is.na((df %>% dplyr::filter(district_type == "U.S. Senate"))$district_number))

## Summary function edited
historical.turnout.summary <- function(adf,
                                       district.type = "U.S. Senate",
                                       district.number = NULL,
                                       years = c(2012, 2014, 2016)) {
    s <-
      adf[which(
        adf$district_type == district.type &
          # adf$district_number == district.number &
          adf$year %in% years
      ), ]
    if (!is.null(district.number)) {
      s <- 
        s[which(s$district_number == district.number)]
    }
    df <- ddply(
      s, "year",
      function(x) {
        year <- x$year[1]
        total.turnout <- sum(x$total_turnout)
        total.registration <- sum(x$total_registration)
        return(
          data.frame(
            year = year,
            total.turnout = total.turnout,
            total.registration = total.registration
          )
        )
      }
    )
    return(df)
  }

## Re-run
historical.turnout.summary(
  df, 
  district.type = "U.S. Senate", 
  years = c(2012, 2014, 2016) 
)
```

But I'm not 100% sure because you might have read the data off your local file, and while the data uploaded/downloaded from Google Sheets, blanks may have turned to NAs.

With the `district.analyze`, there is an error when you call `major.party.bias` because you try to do numerical operations on expressions such as `"21.39%"` and `"62.81%"`. They will have to be parsed and turned to numeric.

Let me know if this wasn't what you were going for.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help. I can get historical turnout summary to work reliably now, I also switched to using State Senate 19 as my target district because I can use it in the "seat" column countywide also. I switched the % to numerical in the sheet and uploaded that to R, but I have had no luck getting the district analyze function to work.

Comment: @Matt You'll have to post your edited code and the output that you see from your edited code for me to help.

Comment: @Kim- I posted the new code and link to the data above. I'm sure it's not formatted the best way, so I'll keep trying to clean it up. I haven't determined a good way to post the data because there are so many rows. I have provided a new data set that is a little smaller/cleaner. Sorry for taking so long to get back with you.